# Flash Custom Class Management

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class

What's the best way to manage my custom classes without copying and pasting the folder they are contained in into the folder local to my project?
Example, I'm using the Tweener class and I have to copy and past the whole caurina folder into the folder of every project I'm working on.  How do I designate one area for all of my custom classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [classpath](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000775.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to be careful sharing a single library instance across all your projects.

Unless you can automatically recompile and test all your other projects, I would recommend continuing to create copies of any required libraries directly in the projects themselves.

Disk space is cheap, time spent debugging legacy code is not.

Most ActionScript libraries are miniscule.

Many ActionScript libraries are released somewhat frequently with little regard for backwards compatibility.

Newer releases of your libraries may become incompatible with older ones.

As you update libraries, the older ones may become unavailable.

You may occasionally want to edit some library code for a single project, but not be prepared to validate and submit those changes for release (and inclusion in your other projects).

Comment: yes, code ideally should be in some sort of source control and then a copy downloaded for each new project.